# Creating Database Generated Computed Field CodeFirst/EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on trying to create a column in the database via the Initial : Migration file similar to following [this guide](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx).

I have a `Transaction` table and an `Account` table. I'm trying to generate the `Account` property `ReconciledBalance`. It should calculate the SUM of all balances in transactions where `IsReconciled` is true and `IsActive` is true.

```
// Example of calculation
ReconciledBalance = Transactions.Where(t => t.IsActive == true && t.IsReconciled == true).Sum(x => x.Amount)
```

This is what I want to accomplish in the calculated column. I'm wondering if I'm getting close or if I am headed in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated!

```
// Initial.cs file
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Accounts",
        c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            IsActive = c.Boolean(),
            Name = c.String(),
            Balance = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
            //ReconciledBalance = c.Decimal(),
            HouseholdId = c.Int(),
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Households", t => t.HouseholdId);
        Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        //AlterColumn("dbo.Accounts", "ReconciledBalance", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
        DropTable("dbo.Accounts");
    }
}

//Account Model
public class Account
{
    public Account()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [Range(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal ReconciledBalance{ get; set; }
    }

    //FKs
    public int HouseholdId { get; set; }

    //Virtual Properties
    public virtual Household Household { get; set; }// One to one
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

// Account Transaction
public class Transaction
{
    public Transaction()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage ="Description cannot exceed 150 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Range(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public bool IsReconciled { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpense { get; set; }
    [Range(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal ReconciledAmount { get; set; }

    //FKs
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string EnteredById { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    //Virtual Properties
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: If you want to calculate it in the database then you will need to link the `Account` entity to a database view with a calculated field, or use triggers on the Transactions table.

Comment: I've gotten this far with my alter table statement. `Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts ADD ReconciledBalance Decimal SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM [Transactions] WHERE IsReconciled = 1 or IsActive = 1 or IsVoid=0");`

But it's not adding the calculated field. I tried running this in SQL and it's not creating the field either. From the document I linked in OP, it looks like I need the AS operator but SQL doesn't like it when it's in there. Any Ideas?

Comment: Try `Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts ADD ReconciledBalance Decimal AS SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM [Transactions] WHERE IsReconciled = 1 or IsActive = 1 or IsVoid=0");`. I'm not that great with SQL but I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Calculated fields have to use columns in the same table https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could link the entity to a database view with the name expected by Entity Framework instead of a table:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Accounts_BackingTable",
        c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            IsActive = c.Boolean(),
            Name = c.String(),
            Balance = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
            HouseholdId = c.Int(),
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)

        Sql(@"EXECUTE('CREATE view dbo.Accounts 
with schemabinding as (SELECT
    a.id,
    a.isactive,
    a.name,
    a.balance,
    a.householdid,
    SUM(t.amount) AS ReconciledBalance
FROM dbo.accounts_backingtable a
    LEFT JOIN dbo.transactions t
    ON t.accountid = a.id AND t.isactive = 1 AND t.isreconciled = 1
    --It's not clear what logic you need for the join
    --ON t.accountid = a.id AND (t.IsReconciled = 1 or t.IsActive = 1 or t.IsVoid=0)
)
GROUP BY a.id,
    a.isactive,
    a.name,
    a.balance,
    a.householdid')");

    }
```

The GROUP BY clause may mean that your view is not [updateable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187956.aspx), in which case you either need to have two entities, one of which is updateable. Or you could switch to using stored procedures and modify the sql inside the stored procedure.

NB this is still doing the calculation on the fly, just inside the database instead of in the application. If you want it stored in the database, you need to do the calculation when you are creating, updating and deleting transactions.

Comment: I ended up doing this by using [NotMapped] and using a setter to calculate as needed. I'm going to make this the correct answer because I think this is the correct way to use calculated fields. In this scenario, I was trying to calculate a field based on data in another table and from further digging this is similar to what I found. You have to select the data from the other table and calculate the total.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
public class Account
{
    public Account()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [Range(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal ReconciledBalance
    {
        get 
        { 
             return Transactions.Where(t => t.IsActive == true && t.IsReconciled == true).Sum(x => x.Amount) 
        }
        private set { /* needed for EF */ }
    }

    //FKs
    public int HouseholdId { get; set; }

    //Virtual Properties
    public virtual Household Household { get; set; }// One to one
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

And hopefully you don't need to override the Up() or Down(). (**Edit**: or just remove the `Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Accounts NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE");` from it)

Comment: This is a valid approach but if you always do the calculation on the `get`, then the value is never stored in the database. You should remove the `set `and the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute to stop the field being created in the database - it is redundant.

Comment: I originally was going to do it the way that you've shown, but I want the value to be stored in the database. Otherwise I could replace the DatabaseGenerated annotation with the [NotMapped] annotation and calculate it on the fly. I want it to be stored in the DB. Just as @Colin stated.

Comment: You only need the `[NotMapped]` attribute if you have a setter.